# Nginx RTMP/HLS - stream to ffmpeg and output HLS

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, stream, rtmp, http-live-streaming

At this point my solution is working but only as RTMP, i can watch perfectly my stream using the URL:

```
rtmp://X.X.X.X:1935/show/name
```

But the problem is that my LG Smart Tv which uses WebOS don't support RTMP and i would really like to play my stream there. The only solution that i can see right now is to use HLS. With HLS all works fine too, but i need to execute my ffmpeg command before open the HLS stream in TV, otherwise it will not create the files necessary to display the stream on my TV.

So my goal is to serve a stream as HLS without having to trigger the RTMP endpoint or the FFMPEG manually.

I'm really struggling with this, waste 3 days trying to make it work :(

```
http 
{
location /hls 
{
    # Disable cache
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

    # CORS setup
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

    # allow CORS preflight requests
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }

    types {
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
        video/mp2t ts;
    }

    root /mnt/;
    }
}

}
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;

    chunk_size 4000;
    buflen 5s;

    application show {
        live on;

    exec_pull ffmpeg -re -i http://stream-coming.com/$name.ts -c:v libx264 -preset faster -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/$name;

        # Turn on HLS
        hls on;
        hls_path /mnt/hls/;
        hls_fragment 3;
        hls_playlist_length 60;
        # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
        deny play all;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead something like this:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;

        application show {
            live on;

            exec_push ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://stream-coming.com:1935/$name.ts
            -c:v libx264 -preset faster -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name;
            exec_kill_signal term;
        }

        application hls {

            # Turn on HLS
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 12;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            allow publish 127.0.0.1;
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}
```